# При innerHTML значения из форм исчезают

Tags: javascript, html

Приведу в пример небольшой кусок кода:

```js
function fun1() {
    document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML += 'elem';
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <input type="text" id="a">
    <input type="text" id="b">
    <button onclick="fun1()">DO</button>
</div>
```

Примерно я понимаю, почему так происходит, при выполнении innerHTML код заново отрисовывает input, но без значений, которые в нём были. Как можно добавлять элементы через innerHTML, при этом сохраняя значения в input?

Comment: А зачем через innerHTML? Почему не использовать что-нибудь вроде appendChild или хотя бы insertAdjacentHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустите свой пример, введите текст, откройте F12, и вы увидите, что в DOM у инпутов не появляются value с вашим текстом.

```js
var val1;
var val2;
function fun1() {
    val1 = document.getElementById('a').value;
    val2 = document.getElementById('b').value;
    document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML += 'elem';
    document.getElementById('a').value = val1;
    document.getElementById('b').value = val2;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <input type="text" id="a">
    <input type="text" id="b">
    <button onclick="fun1()">DO</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Добавил реализацию в ответ.

Comment: Решил с помощью appendNode(). Спасибо всем, кто дал ответы.

Comment: Это как, причем тут добавление appendNode()?